# How can I use a v-for value in to nuxt link?

Tags: vue.js, for-loop, nuxt.js

I have a loop that loops through an associative array that has text with links

```
links: {'Amount' : '/about', 'Contact' : '/contact'}
```

How can I use the value from my for loop in my nuxt-link? So to="value"?

```
  <ul class="link">
      <li v-for="(link, text) in links" :key="text" :value="link">
          <nuxt-link to=link>{{key}}</nuxt-link>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct. In order to use your JavaScript objects you just have to use model binding just like the following.

```
  <ul class="link">
      <li v-for="(link, text) in links" :key="text" :value="link">
          <nuxt-link :to="link">{{key}}</nuxt-link>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Please note the `:to="link"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<ul class="link">
    <li v-for="(link, index) in links" :key="index">
        <nuxt-link :to="link"> {{ index }}</nuxt-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```